# iAds disabling touches Sprite Kit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I have just implemented iAd into my game. When I run the game the add banner appears at the bottom of the screen. The only problem is that once the test ads complete and start over, there is a small jerk on the screen that disables touches for just a split second. The problem is that the game is a touch based game and when this problem occurs it disables touches long enough for the player to lose the game. So does anyone else have this problem or have had this problem in the past and is there anything I can do to avoid it? I have included the code I use to implement the ads below.

```
//
//  GameViewController.swift
//  Flappy Bird (swift)
//

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var bannerView:ADBannerView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.bannerView?.delegate = self
        self.bannerView?.hidden = false


        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as SKView
           skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
            skView.showsPhysics = false

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)

            self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        println("iAd did load: displaying iAd")
        self.bannerView?.hidden = false
    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        println("iAd will leave")
        return willLeave
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToRecieveAdWithError error: NSError!){
        println("iAd failed to load")
        self.bannerView?.hidden = true
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    println("iAd will leave")
    return willLeave
}
```

Try to return true instead of willLeave or try to delete

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

The rest of the code is exactly like mine and it works fine.